# Подключение Linux-клиента к MacOS-серверу на Си

Tags: linux, c, macos, сокеты

Изучаю сокеты и пытаюсь написать очень простое приложение. Клиент отправляет серверу строку "Hello there!", сервер ее принимает, выводит у себя и отправляет обратно. Написал и клиент (Linux Ubuntu 18.04), и сервер (macOS 10.14.2, IP: 217.144.173.149):

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int sock, listener;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listener < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(2);
    }

    listen(listener, 1);

    while(1)
    {
        sock = accept(listener, 0, 0);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(3);
        }

        while(1)
        {
            bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
            if (bytes_read <= 0) break;
            printf(buf);
            send(sock, buf, bytes_read, 0);
        }

        close(sock);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    char message[] = "Hello there!\n";
    char buf[sizeof(message)];

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3425);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("217.144.173.149");
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }

    send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);
    recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message), 0);

    printf(buf);
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Однако после запуска клиента, он просто зависает и через некоторое время выдает ошибку: `connect: Connection timed out`. Сервер при этом, конечно, работает. Поиск в гугле результатов не дал (может, не так искал). В чем я ошибся?

Comment: А зачем в клиенте делать listen/accept?  Он там совсем не нужен. Если наличие bind ещё можно как то оправдать (хотя в 99% в клиенте оно не нужно), но все его использование в данном коде - нет. Или может Вы скопировали код какого то другого сервера вместо клиента?

Comment: `addr` следует занулять перед использованием. И да, как отмечено выше, код на клиенте на самом деле работает почти как сервер. Вместо того, чтобы соединятся с сервером ваш клиент пытается начать ждать подключений, как будто он имеет IP сервера.

Comment: @KoVadim Я извиняюсь, действительно случайно не то вставил. Правки внес.

Comment: @VTT  Поправил пример.

Comment: А адрес вашего сервера - это белый адрес или он сидит за NAT?

Comment: Если тестируете в пределах одного компа, то можно в качестве адреса сервера указывать просто 127.0.0.1

Comment: @KoVadim учитывая, что клиент и сервер на разных системах, то тогда уж адрес в локалке

Comment: @VTT вероятно, адрес таки серый. Что в таком случае сделать?

Comment: Да, тестирую на одной машине, но инетересно было бы узнать, как все-таки правильно сделать в текущей задаче. Накостылить всегда успею :)

Comment: ага, я все таки прав. Похоже просто виртуалка. А ее нужно ещё правильно настроить и угадать правильный ip. Рассказывайте структуру и программу виртуализации

Comment: @KoVadim изначально пробовал на виртуалке, но сейчас пересел за физику linux, та же история

Comment: В любом случае, Вам нужно разобраться с структурой Вашей сети и адресами в ней. Угадать это очень сложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой пример работает если поправить мелочи:
В сервере:
добавить:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

исправить:

```
printf(buf); -> printf("%s\n", buf);
```

В клиенте:
добавить:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

исправить:

```
printf(buf); -> printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Если с клиента сервер пингуется все работает.